# CUDA : why are we using so many kinds of memories?

Tags: memory, cuda

I've learned the CUDA programming and I went into some problem. The major one is in CUDA "why do we use so many kinds of memories(Global, local, shared, constant, texture, caches,registers)?" unlike in CPU where we have only three main memory(Ram, caches, hd etc).

Comment: Are you sure that on CPU you have only RAM and HD? What about the cache?

Comment: Also the CPU have registers as well. The local memory corresponds to TLS on CPU. Depending on architectures CPU might have even more types but they tend to be of interest only for device drivers (for example 'low memory' for DMA transfers on old systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reasons for having multiple kinds of memory are explained in this article: [Wikipedia: Memory Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy)

To summarize it, it a very simplified form:

- It is usually the case that the *larger* the memory is, the *slower* it is
- Memory can be read and written faster when it is "*closer*" to the processor.

As mentioned in the comment: On the CPU, you also have several layers of memory: The main memory, and several levels of *caches*. These caches are much smaller than main memory, but much faster. These caches are managed by the hardware, so as a software developer, you do not directly notice that these caches exist at all. All the data *seems* to be in the main memory.

On the GPU, you have to manage this memory manually (althogh in newer CUDA versions, you can also declare the shared memory as "cache", and let CUDA take care of the data management).

For example, reading some data from the *shared* memory in CUDA may be done within a few NANOseconds. Reading data from *global* memory may take a few MICROseconds. One of the keys to high performance in CUDA is thus **data locality**: You should try to keep the data that you are working on in *local* or *shared* memory, and avoid reading/writing data in global memory.

(P.S.: The "Close" votes that mark this question as "Primarily Opinion Based" are somewhat ridiculous. The question may show a lack of own research, but is a reasonable question that can clearly be answered here)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. It helped me a lot.

Comment: It is worth noting that different memories are *virtual abstractions* in the CUDA programming model. It is true that they map onto specific hardware features for current hardware, but they don't have to, and they might not in future CUDA platforms. OpenCL has a very similar structure, and it is used on a lot of hardware that doesn't have many of these analogous hardware features.